# Adding Existing Framework to Xcode (iPhone) error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have added the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to my Frameworks folder in my iPhone project and added the `#import "<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>"` statement at the top of a custom `UIView` class.

However the custom UIView class gives me a "No such file or directory" compliation error in relation to the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework. Is there something else I need to set so that the compiler can see the framework.

I'm not expert on the Xcode IDE so any assistance would be extremely welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try removing the quotes around the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

you don't need them when you are importing a framework.

Comment: Thank you so much. Amateur mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // not #import "<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I accepted the answer from Ryan Ferretti as he got there first.